# Minimum Length of Circumradius $R$

Tags: trigonometry

With usual notation, if in a triangle $\Delta ABC$, $a = 3$, $b = 4$ and circumradius R of  is minimum, then the value of $[2rR]$ is (where [.] denotes greatest integer function)

My approach is as follow

$R = \frac{{abc}}{{4\Delta }} \Rightarrow R = \frac{{abc}}{{4rs}} \Rightarrow 2Rr = \frac{{abc}}{{2s}}$

$2s = a + b + c \Rightarrow 2s - 7 = c$

$ \Rightarrow 2Rr = \frac{{12c}}{{c + 7}} \Rightarrow 2Rr = \frac{{12}}{{1 + \frac{7}{c}}}$

Not able to proceed

Comment: "Then the value of $[2rR]$ is..." is what? Also, what do we mean by $r$? Also also, I suggest using the tag "triangles" instead of "trigonometry".

Comment: Your title suggests the problem is minimizing $R$, but it's actually computing $2rR$ when $R$ is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since a side of a triangle is a chord of its circumcircle and at most two circumradii, $R\ge2$, and this is saturated iff $\triangle ABC$ is right-angled with hypotenuse $b$. Now compute the sides, area and $s$, hence $r$ and so on.